# Capturing query duration using selenium & robotframework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am using Selenium and Robotframework.

I want to:

1. submit multiple search values sourced from a csv file
2. capture the search result values and write out to csv file
3. capture the duration of the query

How do I do step #3?
Should I be looking to use HAR and parse that for the duration, or is there a way for selenium and robotframework to access this value for each query and write out to file?

Comment: "looking for guidance" isn't a suitable question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with selenium: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-measure-page-load-times-with-selenium/

Browsermob proxy (HAR) should help you measure the request time, especially of ajax responses: https://www.tothenew.com/blog/browsermob-proxy-for-webpage-load-testing-using-selenium/

However if you're just hitting one endpoint (with different requests), you probably want to look into a tool like jmeter: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html